# Code work slow in blackberry device

Tags: java, blackberry

I have code that work fine but unexpectedly work slow in blackberry device

```
public ContactsScreen()//(Object _app)
    {

     setTitle(new LabelField( "Contacts",LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH));     


       //_contactNamesVector = new Vector();
    _contactVector = new Vector();
    _contacts = getContactListInVector();
       //ReadableList _readableList =(ReadableList) _contacts;
    if(_contacts != null)
    {
     // Create an instance of our SortedReadableList class. 
   //it takes _contacts as vector and then sort it accordingly

     _contactSortedList = new ContactSortedList(_contacts);        

     // Add our list to a KeywordFilterField object.
     _keywordFilterField = new KeywordFilterField()
     {

      protected boolean navigationClick(int status,int time)
      {      
       int index = getSelectedIndex();

       //Return data in redableklist format ie collectionlist and boolean
       ContactInfo data = (ContactInfo)getSelectedElement();
       data.toggleChecked();
       invalidate(index);
       if(data.isChecked())
       {
         // UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(getScreen());
          data.displayMultipleContacts();

        //String str1 = data.getCompanyName();
        //Dialog.alert(str1);
        //String str2 = data.getFirstName();
        //Dialog.alert(str2);
        //String str3 = data.getLastName();
        //Dialog.alert(str3);
        //String str4 = str1.concat(str2).concat(str3);

       }
       return true;
      }
//       public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time){
//        if(key == Keypad.KEY_ENTER){
//        int index = getSelectedIndex();
//          //Return data in redableklist format ie collectionlist and boolean
//          ContactInfo data = (ContactInfo)getSelectedElement();
//          data.toggleChecked();
//          invalidate(index);
//          if(data.isChecked())
//          {
//            // UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(getScreen());
//             data.displayMultipleContacts();
//           
//           //String str1 = data.getCompanyName();
//           //Dialog.alert(str1);
//           //String str2 = data.getFirstName();
//           //Dialog.alert(str2);
//           //String str3 = data.getLastName();
//           //Dialog.alert(str3);
//           //String str4 = str1.concat(str2).concat(str3);
//           
//          }
//         
//        }
//        if(key == Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE){
//         UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(getScreen());
//         
//        }
//        return true;
//       }

     };
     _keywordFilterField.setSourceList(_contactSortedList,_contactSortedList);      

   //register keywordfield with Callbackinterface list display, it call methods of callback 
     _keywordFilterField.setCallback(_contactSortedList);


     _contactSortedList.setReadableList(_keywordFilterField.getResultList());

     // We're providing a customized edit field for
     // the KeywordFilterField.
     CustomKeywordField customSearchField = new CustomKeywordField();
     _keywordFilterField.setKeywordField(customSearchField);        



     // We need to explicitly add the search/title field via MainScreen.setTitle().
     this.setTitle(_keywordFilterField.getKeywordField());            

     // Add our KeywordFilterField to the screen and push the screen
     // onto the stack.
     this.add(_keywordFilterField);
    }

    }
```

Comment: There is an integrated profiler in Eclipse For BlackBerry, have you tried it ?

Comment: Before using a profiler, try to measure the times of the different operations in this method. For example, check how long the getContactListInVector() call takes, and then how long it takes to sort the contacts using ContactSortedList.